# How to print output in similar manner as input?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int index=0;
    char str[1000];
    char c;
    while((c=getchar())!='/')  {
       while((c=getchar())!='\n') {
          scanf("%c",&str[index]);
          index++;
       }
       str[index]='\n';
       index++;
    }
    str[index]='\0';
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

I am giving input in the form of multiple lines ,and I want to display the output in similar fashion as input provided ,I am using '/' character as the end of input ,now I am not getting the output ,how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: `scanf("%999[^/]", str);`

Comment: I can use it but what is the issue in this code ?

Comment: Characters are thrown away that you entered.

Comment: But why , when I am scanning correctly

Comment: `getchar()` removes a character from the input stream.

Comment: @user123 you don't use `c` as input.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, Thanks I got my issue resolved

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, can you please tell how to indicate the end of input without the usage of any external character ,here I have used '/' character,if I want to do it without any character , I used  while(!feof(stdin)) ,but it is not working ,please guide

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you sending an EOF to the stream (e.g. by pressing CTRL-D in Linux or CTRL+W in Windows)?

Comment: I am simply running my code on online compiler and I click on run after giving input ,so how to indicate here end on input ?

Comment: I don't know. You would have to check the documentation for the site you are using (if there is any). Please also note that `feof()` won't return true until you have failed to read from the stream. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: ",I am using '/' character as the end of input" --> not likely to work.  `stdin` if often _line buffered_ so text is not given to the program until a `'\n'` occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading characters from `stdin`, in your case, you have *three* conditions to protect against if you want to terminate the read on `'/'`:

1. `index + 1 < 1000` (to prevent overrun and preserve space for the
   *nul-terminating* char)
2. `(c = getchar()) != '/'` (your chosen terminator); and
3. `c != EOF`  (you don't want to read after `EOF` is set on the
   stream)

Putting those pieces together, you could simply do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1000   /* define a constant (macro) for max chars */

int main (void) {

    int c, idx = 0;
    char str[MAXC] = "";    /* initialize your array (good practice) */

    /* read each char up to MAXC (-2) chars, stop on '/' or EOF */
    while (idx + 1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '/' && c != EOF)
        str[idx++] = c; /* add to str */

    str[idx] = 0; /* nul-terminate (optional here if array initialized, why?) */

    printf ("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

(I would encourage a `putchar ('\n');` after the `printf` (or simply add a `'\n'` to the *format string*) to protect against input without a final POSIX *end-of-line*, e.g. in the event of a stop on `'/'`, or on reaching `1000` chars, or reading from a redirected file that does not contain a POSIX EOL)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getchar_io <../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use this? :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int index=0;
char str[1000];
char c;
while((c=getchar())!='/')  {
  str[index] = c;
  index++;
}
str[index]='\0';
printf("%s",str);
return 0;
}
```